# Is there a PHP CMS with builtin A/B Testing Support?

Tags: php, frameworks, ab-testing

I'm about to start work on a new project and thought it could be a good time to also start looking into a new PHP CMS. I've really only spent a lot of time with Joomla, so "new" can almost be "any".

Anyway, I've also been seeing a lot of talk about A/B testing and thought that it might be a good idea to try. From what I've seen, there's a couple of solutions for Rails, but I was wondering if there are any out there that support PHP CMSs? The more integrated, the better.

Thanks for any suggestions or thoughts...

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a framework that's designed for eCommerce with A/B testing, then [Magento Commerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com) has it built in using Google Web Optimizer.  There is an interesting article [here](http://www.netmediagroup.com/blog/ab-testing-the-one-step-checkout-magento-extension/) on the results of such an experiment.

As you'll quickly find through the google, Magento is not for the faint-hearted, but does offer some serious benefits.

Enjoy,
JD

Comment: I've done some work with Magento before... it's definitely 'interesting'. Thanks for the heads up on its integration though. Plus, reminding me of "Google Web Optimizer" gives me something else to search for specifically when looking for frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a new library: http://phpabtest.com which should serve your purpose.

Comment: I saw that, though was a little put off by the commercial aspect of it, as well as the reliance on Google Analytics (not that that's a game stopper, but I would prefer it to all be internal). Good link, though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't these types of tests more on application level? I have never seen any php framework support it anyway :)

But if you need a suggestion for framework... Yii, Lithium, Zend Framework, Symfony are all good choices :)

Comment: True, it's definitely more at an application level. I guess I'm looking for something similar to A/Bingo for Rails, but for PHP... the easier it is for me the better :s