# A/B Testing Frameworks for PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, ab-testing

What are the good A/B Testing frameworks for PHP, and why?

NOTE: I do NOT want a huge/generic framework that also has a/b testing support - I want a small framework specific to AB testing. Hence, not a duplicate question.

Comment: refer to this already answered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445167/any-php-framework-with-builtin-a-b-testing-support

Comment: this is a different question. it's asking about general/large PHP Frameworks with a/b testing support -- I'm asking about a small framework specific-to a/b tests

Answer (score 3):

I would try the [phpabtest framework](http://phpabtest.com/quick-start).  It's small, compact, easy to use.

Comment: Looks nice, but I don't like how it relies on output buffering to parse it's special template tags. Seems like if you rely on output buffering for other stuff it might interfere. Also it seems like it only lets you track results via Google Analytics rather than a database?

Comment: @philfreo, are you looking to test entirely different pages/views?  Another option is to use something like codeigniter as a frame work and add some basic logic to alternate views and track conversions through it.  It might be a little heavier than your looking for though.

Comment: Nope -- just parts within a page. But actually I see that there's an alternative way to use this framework without the `{phpab}` template tags: http://phpabtest.com/documentation#php-variations

Comment: @philfreo, that is actually where I was going to point you next depending on your response to my last comment ;)  Good luck!

Comment: Another problem is the license: `phpA/B requires paid license fee for commercial use. Contact bcrayzie@gmail.com for commercial license requests`. Looks like I may be writing my own :)

Comment: @philfreo - looks like the license has changed: `phpA/B is licensed under a GNU General Public License, version 2`

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [PHP-redis-A-B-Testing](https://github.com/aliasaria/PHP-redis-A-B-Testing) , which  uses Redis for great performance and doesn't have the commercial license limitations of phpabtest or the limits caused by its tie-ins to google analytics.

Comment: PHPA/B's License changed... it's now free for commercial use...   GPLv2